# What's the proper entry point for a Spring application?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, ant

I'm using Ant to launch a Spring application via an XML file. The XML file creates a few beans and enables component-scan.

Once the Spring container is initialized and all of the Spring beans are created, I obviously need to actually run the code that the application is meant to run. I tried adding the code to a `@PostConstruct` method on one of the beans, but that causes weird problems because `@PostConstruct` is called before the entire Spring application is finished being instantiated.

What's the equivalent of a `main()` method in a Spring application to actually run the stuff you want to run after the Spring container has **finished** starting up?

Comment: What about after the `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` in the main method of the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication? Or is your app not with spring boot?

Comment: I'm not using `@SpringBootApplication`, all I have is an XML file which defines some spring beans and enables component-scan.

Comment: You don't have any Java class file?

Comment: I have a bunch of Java classes which are `@Component`s, but no I don't have any main Java file which is running the whole application or anything like that.  In fact I don't have a `main()` method at all...

Answer (score 0):

Clubbed all the xml that you want to load inside an application-context.xml located in the classpath

For example : application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC  "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>

    <import resource="classpath:DataSourceContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:HibernateContext.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:PropertyContext.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Load all the xml using in custom MyBeanLoader using the application-context.xml

```
public class MyBeanLoader {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
    }
}
```

Now make this as a starter main class file in the ant.xml

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/HelloWorld.jar" basedir="build/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.MyBeanLoader"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

If you want to run the logic after Spring's context start, you can use the ApplicationListener and the event ContextRefreshedEvent.

```
 @Component
 public class StartupApplication implements 
 ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

 @Override
 public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    // call you logic implementation
}
```

}

Hope that will solve your problem

Comment: Well I guess that's one way to work around the problem. There's really no annotation or anything in the spring framework that will signal a class/method to get executed after spring initialization has finished?

Comment: You can use ApplicationListener interface and override the onApplicationEvent method